# Using to_pickle for very large dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, serialization

I have a very large dataframe having a shape (16 million, 147). I am trying to persist that dataframe using to_pickle but program is neither serializing that dataframe nor throwing any exception. Does anyone have any idea about it? Suggest me any other format for persisting dataframe. I have tried hdf5 but I am having mixed type object hence I cannot use that format.

Comment: So what happens instead? Does the file at *path* get created, but left empty? How long does the call take, does it return immediately, or does it take some time? Did you use compression?

Comment: file at path is not created. I have't use compression. Call is not returning for hours.

Comment: So is it a regular path? Because in that case the file is opened immediately, and from that point onwards exists (albeit empty). I don't know what the limitations of dataframe pickling are, since a single pickle object is produced I can definitely see that it would take a looooong time to pickle 16 million rows.

Comment: Also, why not just use HDF5? It's vastly superior to Pickle when it comes to performance, especially at data sizes like these. Hell, at these sizes, CSV with compression is probably better too.

Comment: thanks @Martijn Pieters for suggesting csv with compression.